# Questions like "what are practical applications of X"

Tags: discussion, questions

Are Questions like "(Where) will I ever need Automaton-Theory / P/NP / ... after I finished my studies?" okay? They are kind of meta-y, but somewhat related to CS and I have no idea where you would ask these questions if not here.

Example Questions would be:

- Where will I need P/NP-theory after I got my degree?
- What are the practical applications of Petri-Nets outside the university?
- ...

Comment: I don't like these kinds of questions. They taste like "Please legitimate that I have to learn this.". On the other hand, they can be honestly curious, so I don't know what we should do.

Comment: @Raphael they were obviously meant in the second way, but I figured the same as you did, so I wanted to try and clear things up before asking.

Comment: I think it depends on the phrasing then. If the question proposes one or two ideas like "Do X and Y work, where can I find more?" or "I can't get theory X to work on problem Y like this [...]. What is wrong?" (I feel like an enthusiast should have such ideas) it is a good question, imho.

Comment: @Raphael but if I cannot imagine anything "useful" you can do with, for example, automaton theory (outside of theoretical CS), how should I ask the question? Or should I just not ask at all?

Comment: I think somebody interested in automata would "see" potential uses. Anyway, I guess that [websearch](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=applications+automata+theory) should lead you to pointers quickly, which allows you to ask a focused question.

Comment: For example: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8539/how-practical-is-automata-theory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think asking for applications of a (theoretical) topic is completely fine. The issue is *how* to ask them so they don't end up being "non-constructive" or "too broad".

Comment: I agree with this sentiment. I would extend by saying that these sort of questions are often easy to come up with, and so we should hold them to a higher standard of quality. We need to make sure they are unambiguously constructive and properly scoped.